# Matching data depending on chosen preferences

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to build a workout app using `Vue`, where you can generate a workout depending on chosen preferences. An user can select some options and then click button to generate a workout. Collected data is an `object` of `arrays` and each `array` contains `objects` of chosen options (for example: allowed duration of a workout, difficulty, prefered exercises)

```
this.generatorData = {
  types: [],
  style: [],
  muscleGroups: [],
  difficulty: [
    { title: 'Beginner', ..some properties },
    { title: 'Intermediate', .. }
  ]
}
```

I also have a set of exercises that have the same properties as a generated `object`, but are predefined.

```
exercises: [
  {
    title: 'Name',
    type: 'Weights',
    style: ['Strength Building'],
    muscleGroups: ['Back', 'Chest'],
    difficulty: 'Intermediate'
  },
  {
    title: 'Name',
    type: 'Weights',
    style: ['Strength Building'],
    muscleGroups: ['Back', 'Chest'],
    difficulty: 'Intermediate'
  }
]
```

I would like to match exercises with data/preferences object. Here's a function but unfortunately I was only able to hardcode it and it doesn't work as expected. I need to compare data from `this.generatorData` with `exercises` - loop through all exercises and find these that match the requirements.  Is there a way to make it work and if it is possible how do I automatise this function?

```
 match() {
     let categories = Object.values(this.generatorData)
     for(let category of categories) {
         if(category.length > 1) {
             this.exercises.filter(exercise => {
                 if(exercise.type === category[0].name || exercise.type === category[1].name || exercise.type === category[2].name) {
                     if(exercise.difficulty === category[categories.length - 1].name) {
                         this.matchedExercies.push(exercise)
                     }
                 }
             })
         }
         else if(category.length === 1) {
             let filtered = this.exercises.filter(exercise => exercise.type === category[0].name)
             console.log(filtered)
             this.matchedExercies = filtered
         }
     }
 }
```

Here's a [codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/34xxvnoxwq).

Comment: Can you share the full example of `this.generatorData` and `exercises`? Object names not matching. What data type will be inside arrays? Is there object like array of difficult? or like this difficult: ['easy', 'hard']? In short, please give us real example data.

Comment: the first occurrence of `this.exercises.filter(exercise => {...` result is not assigned to any variable

Comment: also when you use `Object.values(this.generatorData)` you remove the key, which is the name of the category

Comment: I've added a demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/34xxvnoxwq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so this is a matter of plain js, not so much vue.

Assuming the filtering is done using AND across filters and OR across filter choices, here is a working version (requiring some changes to the schema)

```js
// the values are in an array, to use the `title` some changes may be needed
const generatorData = {
  types: [],
  style: [],
  muscleGroups: [{name:'Back'}],
  difficulty: [{name:'Beginner'},{name:'Intermediate'}]
}

const exercises = [
  {
    title: 'Name',
    type: 'Weights',
    style: ['Strength Building'],
    muscleGroups: ['Toes', 'Chest'],
    difficulty: 'Intermediate'
  },
  {
    title: 'Name',
    type: 'Weights',
    style: ['Strength Building'],
    muscleGroups: ['Back', 'Chest'],
    difficulty: 'Intermediate'
  },
  {
    title: 'Name',
    type: 'Weights',
    style: ['Strength Building'],
    muscleGroups: ['Back', 'Chest'],
    difficulty: 'Effin Hard'
  }
]
// I loop over the categories first, removing any that are not needed
const categories = Object.keys(generatorData).map(k => {
  // if you want to keep using `title`, this is a good place to do that (val from all titles)
 if (generatorData[k].length > 0) return { key: k, val: generatorData[k].map(g => g.name) };;
  return false
}).filter(i => i !== false);

let filtered = exercises.filter(e => {
  // filter all categories, and compare length of matching filters with the number of filters (enforces AND rule)
  return categories.filter(f => {
    // if key is missing, assume true
    if (e[f.key] === undefined) return true;
    // loop through filter values and make sure at leas one matches (OR condition)
    return f.val.filter(v => {
      // handle string as direct match
      if (typeof e === "string") return e[f.key] === v;
      // handle array with `includes`
      return e[f.key].includes(v)
    }).length > 0
  }).length === categories.length;
})

console.log(filtered)
```

---

update

Looking at the codesandbox, it looks like your store is actually providing the generatorData with `name` instead of `title`

instead of:

```
difficulty: [
  { title: 'Beginner', ..some properties },
  { title: 'Intermediate', .. }
]
```

it uses:

```
difficulty: [
  { name: 'Beginner'},
  { name: 'Intermediate'}
]
```

the code was updated to use array of objects with `name`

Comment: Thank you very much, I've tried to update my demo to include your code. I get an error at: `return e[f.key].includes(v)
            }).length > 0`  - `Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined`

Demo is updated, so if it is possible you could see an error in real time.

Comment: `e[f.key]` is undefined

Comment: that's because your filter has `length` and the exercise does not. You can fix it by adding `if (e[f.key] === undefined) return true;` updated example.

Comment: I've added some real `exercises` to my demo in `store.js` and now everytime at the end I get an empty array `(filtered)`.

Comment: `e[f.key].includes(v)` always gets `false`.

Comment: I mentioned an issue with the use of `type` in the generatorData that is likely causing the issue. I'll update with the relevant change

Comment: I had to change `e[f.key].includes(v)` to `e[f.key].includes(v.name)` and now it works, however it still doesn't work when it comes to `type` property, as it is ignored when matching data.

Comment: one object uses `type` and the other uses `types`, could be related

Answer (score 1):

This can be better for complex selections.

```
    matchPreferencesWithExercises() {
      let categories = this.generatorData;
      this.exercises.map(exercise => {
        let error = 0;
        let matched;

        for (let categoryName in categories) {
          if (exercise[categoryName]) {
            if (typeof exercise[categoryName] === "string") {
              !categories[categoryName]
                .map(item => item.name)
                .includes(exercise[categoryName]) && error++;
            } else {
              matched = 0;
              exercise[categoryName].map(exerciseAttr => {
                categories[categoryName].includes(exerciseAttr) && matched++;
              });
            }
          }
        }
        (error === 0 || matched > 0) && this.matchedExercies.push(exercise);
      });
    }
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/qo74o6z9